# Do StackExchange websites use SOUNDEX from SQL Server?

Tags: discussion

Hey

I'm wondering if SE websites are using [SOUNDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms187384.aspx) from SQL Server, and where if any?

and if not, where would it be possible to include it?

Maybe it is being used in the comment notifications system so if I wrote @LrdCover get a real

notification to LordCover, based on the similarity between the 2 words.

Comment: Not sure if Messrs. LirdCover, LerdCover and LuredCover would be too happy to get notified alongside (a.k.a. false positives, all those map to soundex `L63216`), just that you could omit, what, one **single** letter? To me, that looks like you're asking the dev team for a lot of effort so that you could get such a tiny convenience.

Comment: @Piskvor I think that the notifications should only be checked against the contributed users for that specific question (by answers and comments alongside the question) and then this feature would be mass-decreasing the error-prone thing.

Comment: Hmm, it still sounds complicated (for negligible benefit - is it so crucial that you get a comment notification?) and expensive (a multiple-join query in the DB to get the soundexes of all the participating users) to me.